# カスタムセルを用いたTableViewにて表示させたセルをセクション分けして再表示させたい

Tags: swift, swift3

カスタムセルを利用したTableViewで表示させたセルに対し、配置したボタンを押下することで、セクション毎に分けられたTableViewを再表示させたいと考えております。

カスタムセルを用いたTbaleViewの表示、ボタンの配置まではできたのですが、その後、どのようにセクション毎に分け、TableViewを再表示させればよいのか分からないため、ご教授願います。

現状の画面イメージとボタン押下後の画面イメージは下記のとおりです。

＜現状の画面（イメージ）＞[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

＜ボタン押下後の画面イメージ＞[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

カスタムセルの作成方法は下記サイトを参考にほぼそのままの内容で実装いたしました。

・初めてでも分かる！カスタムセルをSwiftで使用する方法
http://yuu.1000quu.com/use_a_custom_cell_in_swift

データ構造は配列で下記のように用意しております。
・画像データ

```
let image = ["A.jpg", "B.jpg", "C.jpg", "D.jpg"] //ここでは4つの画像ファイルを用意しております。
```

・上記画像データに対するタグ

```
let tag = ["A", "B", "A", "A"]　//「A.jpg」のタグは「A」となります。
```

・上記画像データに対する日付

```
let date = ["2016/06/25", "2016/06/24", "2016/06/23", "2016/06/22"] //「A.jpg」の日付は「2016/06/25」となります。
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView に複数のセクションでセルを表示するには、[UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)の

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

メソッドを実装し、セクションの数を返すようにしてください。
一覧、タグ別、日付別のどのボタンが選択されているのかを判定して、
日付別なら `1` 、タグ別なら存在するタグの種類の数を返すことになるでしょう。

すでに日付別の表示ができているのなら、以下のメソッドは実装ずみだと思います。

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

こちらも選択中のボタンにあわせて、
それぞれ適切な内容を返すように変更してください。

また、ボタン押下時に表示データを切り替えるには、テーブルビューに対して、`reloadData`メソッドを呼んでください。

なお、以下のようなデータの持ち方

> let image = ["A.jpg", "B.jpg", "C.jpg", "D.jpg"]
>      let tag = ["A", "B", "A", "A"]　//「A.jpg」のタグは「A」となります。
>      let date = ["2016/06/25", "2016/06/24", "2016/06/23", "2016/06/22"]

をしていると、タグ別や日付別でデータの並び順が変化することに対応するのがとても難しくなります。
セル1つ分のデータをまとめた struct または class を定義して、その型の配列としてデータを持つことをおすすめします。

Comment: SAWA様、曖昧な質問にも関わらず、ご丁寧な回答誠にありがとうございます。
おっしゃるとおり、現状のデータの持ち方ですと、並び順の変化の対応が難しいと感じております。
私自身Swiftの初心者ということもあり、struct、classの使い方がわかっておりませんので、今回の場合どのようなstruct、classを作れば良いかご教授いただけますと幸いです。

重ねての質問となり大変恐縮ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: structやclassを使って目的にあったデータ型を作ることはSwiftあるいはオブジェクト思考プログラミングの基本になります。ここを曖昧な理解のまま「とりあえず動けばOK」という姿勢で進めるのは危険だと思います。「Swift 入門」などで検索して書籍等で学習されることをおすすめします。

Comment: ご丁寧なアドバイスありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、オブジェクト指向の基礎を学び、自分なりに開発したいと思います。